# jwplayer causes animation errors on tablet

Tags: android, ios, jquery-ui, tablet, jwplayer

This issue has been solved. See the JSFiddle examples below to see the original errors, and scroll to solution to see the working version.

JWPlayer v6:
[Link to preview on tablet devices](http://jsfiddle.net/Gj5jh/embedded/result/) (JSFiddle)
[Link to view full code](http://jsfiddle.net/Gj5jh/) (JSFiddle)

JWPlayer v5:
[Link to preview on tablet devices](http://jsfiddle.net/9d9K3/embedded/result/) (JSFiddle)
[Link to view full code](http://jsfiddle.net/9d9K3/) (JSFiddle)

2/10/14 (UPDATE) - In the JSFiddle example provided, I updated jwplayer to version 6 (I was previously using v5) and now the animation errors are occurring on desktop as well. The errors are specifically a result of animations carried on in the `leftVideoPriority()` and `rightVideoPriority()` functions. This can be confirmed by commenting out calls to those functions in the `stop` property of the draggable object. On another note, using CSS animations rather than jQuery animations may be a solution to this problem, but it may eliminate support for IE9 and definitely IE8. This is (unfortunately) not acceptable for my purposes.

I am trying to develop an animating dual-video "widget," if you will, that allows users on both desktop and tablet devices to interact with the widget. It contains two videos, placed side by side, and separated by a "control bar". That control bar can be dragged along the x-axis to bring either the left or right video into focus. Additionally, either video can be clicked/tapped to toggle it into focus. Please view the example to see exactly how it works.

This widget utilizes jwplayer, jQuery UI, & jquery UI touch (a plugin that binds touch events to the mouse event listeners defined in my code).

The widget works correctly on desktop using Chrome (I have not carried out cross-browser compatibility testing just yet), but there are some errors that happen as a result of the event interaction/animation on tablet devices (specifically iOS and Android). The errors (they appear to be more like quirky css than "errors" per se) are similar on both iOS and Android but differ in that on iOS the error disappears when the animation stops; on Android the error sticks after the animation is done.

The problem also seems to stem from jwplayer, as removing the code blocks associated with it resolve the animation errors on tablets.

Here is an excerpt from my jQuery UI code that executes animations on "draggable" events:

```
$("#centerBar").draggable({
        axis: "x",
        containment: "#centerBarContainer",
        scroll: false,
        drag: function (event, ui) {

            centerOfHandleFromLeft = ui.offset.left + 25; //get distance from left edge of document to the handle's center

            centerBarPosDelta = centerOfHandleFromLeft - initialHandleFromLeft; // calculate change in center bar position

            // adjust width of video containers according to center bar movement
            $("#videoContainerLeft, #videoContentLeft_wrapper").css({
                "width": centerBarPosDelta + initialLeftVideoWidth
            });
            $('#videoContainerRight, #videoContentRight_wrapper').css({
                "width": initialRightVideoWidth - centerBarPosDelta
            });
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {

            // check if change in center bar position is more/less than half the width of its draggable area
            if (centerBarPosDelta <= (barContainerWidth / 2)) {
                rightVideoPriority();
            } else {
                leftVideoPriority();
            }
        }
    });
```

And here are the animation code blocks:

```
function leftVideoPriority() {
        $('#videoContainerLeft, #videoContentLeft_wrapper, #videoContentLeft').stop().animate({
            "width": 580
        }, 750);
        $('#videoContainerRight, #videoContentRight_wrapper, #videoContentLeft').stop().animate({
            "width": 220
        }, 750);
        $('#centerBar').stop().animate({
            "left": 360
        }, 750);

        currentVideo = 'left';
        enableVideoSound();
    }

    function rightVideoPriority() {
        $('#videoContainerRight, #videoContentRight_wrapper, #videoContentRight').stop().animate({
            "width": 580
        }, 750);
        $('#videoContainerLeft, #videoContentLeft_wrapper, #videoContentLeft').stop().animate({
            "width": 220
        }, 750);
        $('#centerBar').stop().animate({
            "left": 0
        }, 750);

        currentVideo = 'right';
        enableVideoSound();
    }

    function enableVideoSound() {
        if (currentVideo == 'left') {
            jwplayer('videoContentLeft').setVolume(60);
            jwplayer('videoContentRight').setVolume(0);
        } else {
            jwplayer('videoContentRight').setVolume(60);
            jwplayer('videoContentLeft').setVolume(0);
        }
    }
```

In conclusion, I have tried several variants of jQuery UI touch - [jquery ui touch punch, for example](http://touchpunch.furf.com/) - but the animation error persists. I am satisfied with the tablet event listener functionality, it's just the animation errors that need to be changed. Unfortunately, I have no idea what could be causing them as I am not familiar with tablet/mobile development, and the visible errors do not seem to closely reflect any html element in the DOM (perhaps it is related to #centerBarContainer, as it appears similar in size/positioning, but the visible errors seems to move in a way that #centerBarContainer does not).

/edit/ - please excuse any messiness / lack of optimization in my code... I had to strip this down to the version you see here from a more complete version, and some lines of code may not make sense out of that context. Everything that is pertinent to this issue has been included, however.

Comment: Have you tried testing out JW6 as well to see if this issue happens? I noticed you are using JW5 which is not longer actively developed.

Comment: [Within the JSfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/xDC3n/), I linked to the jwplayer code provided with a free account (v6.8.4616) and removed the previous jwplayer code (v5.10.2295). The result was that the animation errors now appear on desktop, as well - this may assist in debugging the error, but it was obviously not the desired result. Also, the animation error seems to 'squeeze' the left video to a smaller size, while the previously shown error did not affect the size of the left video.

Comment: Have you tried to just do the animations purely with CSS3 and not using any jQuery at all for them?

Comment: I would love to do this, but unfortunately I must offer support for IE8-9. I may be mistaken about whether CSS3 animations would or would not be compatible for IE9 for this specific project, as I have been jumping between things all day today. Either way, IE8 is out of the picture.

Comment: Okay, got it. What Android version and device does this issue happen on?

Comment: Unfortunately I will not have access to tablets until Monday. I may be able to reach out to the device owners over the weekend to find out what OS version / specific device they use. Were you able to replicate the issue by viewing that jsfiddle example on a tablet?

Comment: I didn't have access to a tablet then either, which is why I asked. I will have access to a Nexus 7 on Monday that I can test with, though.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance so far. I had used an HP Touchpad with Android 4.0.4 as well as an iPad (will get the exact specs on the iPad asap - the owner is currently busy)

Comment: What browser on the desktop do you have the issues with now? I am not seeing what you are talking about in Firefox at least.

Comment: I believe I have found a solution! It seems that the animation functions were overzealous in their scope. Originally, when using jwplayer v5, it was necessary to include the video container element as well as that same element plus "`_wrapper`" which was added to the DOM on load by some inherent property of jwplayer. Turns out animating this element was not ever necessary, and removing it in the animation functions resulted in a correction of the animation error. That may be why you do not see it in your browser (I was using Chrome) because I have since updated the base version of that jsfidle

Comment: Ah, glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureka! Before I explain the solution, please understand that I originally used jwplayer v5 for this project, but updated to v6 per [Ethan JWPlayer's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1645000/ethan-jwplayer) recommendation. This change resulted in a different structure of jwplayer within the DOM. Due to the change, I had to tweak the animation functions to apply to the newly correct elements; doing this led me to accidentally find a solution to the animation errors on both tablet and desktop.

Originally, the animation function looked like this:

```
function leftVideoPriority() {
        $('#videoContainerLeft, #videoContentLeft_wrapper, #videoContentLeft').stop().animate({
            "width": 580
        }, 750);
        $('#videoContainerRight, #videoContentRight_wrapper, #videoContentRight').stop().animate({
            "width": 220
        }, 750);
        $('#centerBar').stop().animate({
            "left":360
        }, 750);

        currentVideo = 'left';
        enableVideoSound();
    }
```

The jQuery objects that were calling the `animate()` method were changed to:

```
$('#videoContainerLeft').animate({...});
$('#videoContainerRight').animate({...});
```

For v6, one additional change was needed: `.jwmain { width:600px; }` in the css

Removing the unnecessary animation on additional elements seems to have corrected the errors. I can't claim to understand why they caused the errors to occur in the first place, however.

This change solved the error for both jwplayer v6 & also worked with v5 by also including `#videoContentLeft_wrapper` and its equivalent `#videoContentRight_wrapper` in the animated jQuery objects. In both cases, `#videoContentLeft` and `#videoContentRight` were removed to correct the animation errors.

[Here is the working version (with code)](http://jsfiddle.net/xDC3n/) and [another version (without code, for tablet testing)](http://jsfiddle.net/xDC3n/embedded/result) - I will update the original post's jsfiddle examples to show the error as it originally existed.